# Why does constructor turn to method when brackets added?

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I am writing a class and whenever I start to write my constructor the text turns blue indicating it is relating the class, however, as soon as I add my () brackets for arguments, it turns black as if it were a normal method and the compiler complains that it needs a return type.

Here is the main form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kat 
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Cat[] catArray = new Cat[7];

    catArray[0] = new Cat("Tom", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 10);
    Cat tiger2 = new Cat("Kyle", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 4);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

And here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kat
{
class Cat
{
    private string _name, _species, _country;
    private char _gender;
    private int _age;

    public Cat(string name, string species, string country, char gender, int age)
    {
        _name = name;
        _species = species;
        _country = country;
        _gender = gender;
        _age = age;
    }
}
}
```

And it definitely doesn't work because I can't use it to construct an object.  This is an exact copy from my IDE and it is in a namespace with the main class.

The error in the main class is:
"Error  3   Method must have a return type"
And
"Error  1   Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)"
And
"Error  8   'Kat.Form1.catArray' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'"
And
"Error  10  The type or namespace name 'tiger1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

There are more errors but they are more or less repeats.

It seems that the object will instantiate if you create it the traditional "Cat tiger1 = ...", but when you try to put it into the Array the errors really appear.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: It works fine for me, but I will add that a default, empty constructor is redundant unless you also specify a parametrised one. Do you get a compilation error?

Comment: If the code does not compile, try rebooting VS, sometimes it gets error happy, and a quick restart wakes it back up.

Comment: Make sure in your code the spelling **and** capitalization are the same, I'm assuming the code you have above is not a copy/paste from your IDE.

Comment: Is it in a namespace?

Comment: Exact copy from IDE, in same namespace, etc...  It is just when I add the brackets.

Comment: there should be somewhere else causing this error.

Comment: Paste your whole file for us in the original question if you don't mind. Namespace, usings, everything...

Comment: Are you sure you made a c# project and not a c++

Comment: And yea, try making a branch new console application from scratch, and just paste that class in there and try compiling

Comment: If this is an exact copy of what you have in your file, looks to me you're missing the `namespace` declaration to wrap the class in.

Comment: I think the namespace is the same as the classname, which isn't allowed

Comment: The namespace can be the same name as the class.  Copied this code right out of the IDE and iterator compiles fine.  That said, a namespace is also not required.

    namespace Cat
    {
        class Cat
        {
            private string _name, _species, _country;
            private char _gender;
            private int _age;

            public Cat()
            {

            }
        }
    }

Comment: Updated the question with my exact errors and a full copy.  Seems to be an error with arrays now, because the object instantiates the traditional way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have non-initialization code outside of a method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Cat[] catArray = new Cat[7];

    catArray[0] = new Cat("Tom", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 10);  // not legal
    Cat tiger2 = new Cat("Kyle", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 4);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

put it inside the form's constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Cat[] catArray = new Cat[7];

    Cat tiger2 = new Cat("Kyle", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 4);


    public Form1()
    {
        catArray[0] = new Cat("Tom", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 10);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The algorithms that the compiler uses to parse code are getting tripped up my the invalid syntax and can't accurately describe what the real problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

1. A ***constructor*** must have the exact same name as the enclosing class (struct), and it must not have a return type.
2. A ***method*** must have a name that is distinct from the name of the class (struct), and it must include a return type (which could be `void` or a normal type).

If you try to make a hybrid between 1. and 2. above, you get the compile-time error.

When you start typing:

```
public Cat
```

the development environment (Visual Studio) will think `Cat` is the type of a method, property or field. That happens when you continue with a space and the name of that member. When instead you continue with an opening parenthesis:

```
public Cat(
```

the development environment realizes that this must be a constructor (no type, just the member name), and it therefore changes to the color used for members, instead of the color used for *types* of members.

---

I see more details in your question now. You have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  Cat[] catArray = new Cat[7];

  catArray[0] = new Cat("Tom", "Tiger", "India", 'm', 10);
```

The last of those two lines is illegal. You cannot have an array entry assignment directly inside a class like that. Consider moving that to the constructor body: `public Form1() { catArray[0] = ... }`

Comment: How does this answer the question? Why is this getting upvoted?

Comment: @SethKitchen I had not guessed that he had the `catArray[0] = ...` stuff at the class member level. I added a remark about that, but D Stanley was faster. Maybe I was upvoted because I explained the part about the text color changing upon typing `(`.